# NHibernate simple collection of joined-subclass entities

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm trying to map a set of joined-subclass entities to a parent entity. The SQL being produced by NHibernate seems to be incorrect. Am I missing anything in my mapping? Is there another way I can approach this problem?

```
<class name="ResultItem" table="result">

  <id name="ID">
    <generator class="identity" />
  </id>

  <many-to-one name="Job" column="JobID"/>
  <property name="Timestamp"/>
  <many-to-one name="User" column="UserID"/>

  <joined-subclass name="ResultItemAttachment" table="result_attachment">
    <key column="ID"/>
    <property name="Comment"/>
  </joined-subclass>

</class>
```

This is the SQL being generated by NHibernate. It seems as if its getting confused between super and sub class members? The only table with JobID is the result table and not result_attachment.

```
SELECT attachment0_.JobID as JobID1_,
       attachment0_.ID as ID1_,
       attachment0_.ID as ID26_0_,
       attachment0_1_.JobID as JobID26_0_,
       attachment0_1_.`Timestamp` as Timestamp26_0_,
       attachment0_1_.UserID as UserID26_0_,
       attachment0_.`Comment` as Comment33_0_
FROM result_attachment attachment0_
inner join result attachment0_1_ on attachment0_.ID=attachment0_1_.ID
WHERE attachment0_1_.JobID=?;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The mapping looks good to me. Could you post the query?

Comment: The mapping is fine. Could you show ResultItem and ResultItemAttachment classes?

Comment: Where do you see result_attachment.JobID in the query? attachment0_1_ is an alias of result.

Comment: @florian-lim The query being produced by NHibernate is there.

Comment: @jakub-linhart

    public abstract class ResultItem : DataObject
    {
        public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }

    public class ResultItemAttachment : ResultItem
    {
        public virtual string Comment { get; set; }
    } - apologies for the lack of breaks, haha

Comment: @stefan-steinegger - attachment0_ is an alias for result_attachment, and as u said, attachment0_1_ is an alias for result. So the query should be selecting attachment0_1_.JobID instead of both attachment0_.JobID since it doesn't exist?

Comment: I'm currently running into the exact same problem... any luck yet? If i find the problem i'll comment here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid this is currently a bug in NHibernate (in there since 2.1 :|) apperently there is a fix in the current alpha of 3.2

https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1747

Possible work around is to manually fetch the bag at runtime. Hardly ideal, other option would be to try and get the alpha version running but running an alpha in a production environment is hardly a great idea.

Comment: Thanks mate. I'll keep an eye out for a stable version of 3.2.

Comment: Same here, i hate having to code around this now :( ruined my day! :'(